# File extensions supported in onlyoffice server

Tags: windows, server, onlyoffice

I have deployed Integration Edition of OnlyOffice server on Windows. Now I came to know that few file formats such as docm, .png, .jpg etc are not supported while some file extensions are supported by onlyoffice server for editing.
So I wanted to know the file on server where the list of supported and unsupported files can be found?

Answer (score 0):

Supported
[Documents Formats](http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/ONLYOFFICE-Editors/ONLYOFFICE-Document-Editor/HelpfulHints/SupportedFormats.aspx)
[Spreadsheet Formats](http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/ONLYOFFICE-Editors/ONLYOFFICE-Spreadsheet-Editor/HelpfulHints/SupportedFormats.aspx)
[Presentation Formats](http://helpcenter.onlyoffice.com/ONLYOFFICE-Editors/ONLYOFFICE-Presentation-Editor/HelpfulHints/SupportedFormats.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to know the configuration file from where the onlyoffice server binaries come to know whether to support a particular file extension or not?

Comment: https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/document-server-integration/blob/master/web/documentserver-example/nodejs/config/default.json#L22